# gfortran doesn't compile real variables

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have written a simple program in Fortran90 to calculate the area of a triangle. The user enters the three sides of the triangle, and then the program outputs the area. Simple enough.

```
MODULE Triangle_Operations
    IMPLICIT NONE
CONTAINS
    FUNCTION Area(x,y,z)
        REAL :: Area  ! function type
        REAL, INTENT( IN ) :: x, y, z
        REAL :: theta, height
        theta = ACOS((x**2+y**2-z**2)/(2.0*x*y))
        height = x*SIN(theta); Area = 0.5*y*height
    END FUNCTION Area
END MODULE Triangle_Operations

PROGRAM Triangle
    USE Triangle_Operations
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL :: a, b, c, Area
    PRINT *, 'Welcome, please enter the &
              &lengths of the 3 sides.'
    READ *, a, b, c
    PRINT *, 'Triangle''s area: ', Area(a,b,c)
END PROGRAM Triangle
```

When I compile this with `gfortran` `gfortran triangle1.f90`, this is the error I receive:

```
triangle1.f90:16.25:

    REAL :: a, b, c, Area
                         1
triangle1.f90:14.8:

    USE Triangle_Operations
        2
Error: Symbol 'area' at (1) conflicts with symbol from module 'triangle_operations', use-associated at (2)
triangle1.f90:19.13:

    READ *, a, b, c
             1
Error: Symbol 'a' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
triangle1.f90:19.16:

    READ *, a, b, c
                1
Error: Symbol 'b' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
triangle1.f90:19.19:

    READ *, a, b, c
                   1
Error: Symbol 'c' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

Why exactly would there be an error thrown for variables `a,b,c`? I have explicitly defined these as reals.

Comment: It compiles (and runs) fine for me.  When I first did it, I named the file `t.f` and that gave errors similar to yours.  When I renamed it to `t.f90` it compiled fine.

Comment: @wallyk It is strange. I have the file named `triangle1.f90`. Perhaps I need to change the extension, or maybe use a specific compiler? I still don't know...

Comment: I think you're getting a cascade of errors from a confused compiler due to multiple declaration of "Area" (the first error). There's no need to declare it REAL in the main program. It's already declared in the module. Removing the declaration fixes everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've defined `Area` twice -- once in your main program and once in the module you import and the names conflict.  You likely think you need to define `Area` in the main program as a holdover from earlier (darker) times when calling a function without an explicit interface.  In modern Fortran, modules provide interfaces automatically and the statement `use Triangle_operations` is enough.

To fix your problem, remove the delcaration of `Area` from your main program, e.g. turn

```
REAL :: a, b, c, Area
```

into

```
REAL :: a, b, c
```

The subsequent errors in your compile output are a result of the first error concerning `Area`.  That entire line gets invalidated so the type declarations of `a`, `b`, and `c` are not processed and this cause the compiler to complain about missing types the next time they are encountered.  These errors will go away once you make the fix suggested above.

---

If your intent had been to have a variable named `Area` in your main program to store the result of the module's function call, you could rename the module symbol, e.g.

```
use triangle_operations, triangleArea => Area
```

and then do this:

```
real a, b, c, Area
Area = triangleArea(a,b,c)
```

in your main program.

Comment: (Just a personal question) I guess in many modern languages, it is generally considered a good practice to import only specific variables or objects to be used in the current scope, rather than implicitly importing everything in a module. So I always make it a rule to use "only" together with "use" in Fortran. What do you think of this practice...? I thought it may also be useful for OP to see the redundant nature of "Area".

Comment: @roygvib As in other languages, sometimes you import everything, sometimes you use `only`. When you use `only` you have to adopt it whenever you add or rename something, but it helps to keep track of the stuff. If you import something to a small subroutine I wouldn’t worry, but sometimes it is handy. There are no strict rules for this.

Comment: @VladimirF Yeah, there is of course no strict rules, and it is also a problem of style. Actually both strategies (i.e., attach only-list always or never attach it) are used in many large programs. Importing everything is also very convenient for short programs. On the other hand, as a program becomes larger, importing everything implicitly into the current scope makes it difficult to keep track of variables. I hope a future version of Fortran will have something like `use, explicit :: mymod` and allow `call mymod% myfunc()` like other languages :)

Comment: (Because this is not related to the OP's question, I will delete my comments later.)